# Is there a way to join different tables from different servers in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

In SQL Server, we've encountered that it is easy to link or to join tables from different servers. But when we try it to MYSQL, we cannot find a way to join those.

Comment: Is there another way aside from Federated Tables?

Comment: Nope - federation is the only way but you may consider putting the tables in different databases which are still on the same server. Then you can simply precede the table names with a dot and the name of the database (on the same server).